# How to download a folder in a private container of Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I can download all files inside a folder in my storage, **if** the container is set as **annonymous** access, using **azcopy** and the following command:

```
AzCopy cp https://.blob.core.windows.net/files/modules/ C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\modules --recursive --log-level NONE & azcopy jobs clean
```

But when I set the container back to private access, it says:

```
failed to perform copy command due to error: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public
INFO: Removed 0 files.
```

I know how to generate the SAS for a unique specific file but in this case that I'm downloading a folder, how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this command:

```
AzCopy cp 'https://<your-storage-name>.blob.core.windows.net/container/<folder>?<your-sas-token>' 'C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\modules' --recursive
```

You can generate SAS token there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Frank! Are you also experiencing low download speed?